# requirejs - how can I get the "baseUrl" info from within a plugin?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm building requirejs plugins and loading them on my page.  On my page, however, I'm setting a baseUrl value, so that I can just load plugins with paths like "tools/foo" instead of "/static/js/blah/tools/foo"

But now I want to allow plugins to load css files.  I want to do this by adding a link to the header, rather than loading the css content with "text!foo.css".  I'd also like not to have to specify a fully qualified path to the css file.  Is there a way for me to pull up the baseUrl setting I set on the page from within a requirejs plugin so I can use that to help find my css files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parentRequire argument to the load function has a parentRequire.toUrl() method that will resolve any path as if it was a module name, but with an extension. So:

```
var cssPath = parentRequire.toUrl('tools/foo.css');
```

would return a path like /static/js/blah/tools/foo.css.

It looks like I forgot to add that to the [plugins doc](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html) page, I'll put in a task to get that documented.

Comment: Thanks!  BTW, I love what the requirejs inheritance pattern has done to my js code.  Thanks for the great tool!